# How to verify that the constructor of another form has been called in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let say I have are two WPF forms: `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` contains a button which should show a message "True" if the constructor of the second form has been called. How can I implement this?

Comment: Sorry but you have to be more precise. Exactly what are you doing? Is it a web or windows forms application?

Comment: Simply place a MessageBox.Show in the form's constructor then?

Or do you really mean to ask what a constructor is?

Comment: Can you expand upon your question?  If you want to get an answer that will help you more detail is needed.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if other forms have been constructed and shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vague question ... to chek if FormXs constructor got called, from inside another class:

Have a static bool (IsConstructed) in the FormX class that is set to true in the constructor ,and then check through FormX.IsConstructed .

In the case of having access to a reference of the form you could just do

```
if(null != ref_name){..}
```

If you want to be notified, consider raising and event ( if a reference is possible) or a command.

A lot of this might depend on your application set up ...

Answer (score 4):

```
MessageBox.Show("true");
```

If you can see the form you can be 100% sure that it has been constructed.

Comment: Then place MessageBox.Show in the constructor of another form.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the constructor for the first time, set some boolean variable to "true".

Comment: Maybe there is a way to to this via reflection. But I dont think System.Reflection can do this. I would take a look at Mono.Cecil, a lot of more powerfull reflection lib.